# Add field in add user form

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to know how I can add a field to the user registration form in Wordpress. I have allready been able to add fields in the edit_user_profile and add_user_profile. But I want to use a custom field in the first step when I register a new user.

Can someone help me?

With kind regards,

Douwe

Answer (score 0):

Best plugin for you: [**Cimy User Extra Fields**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/). This plugin will add some useful fields to registration and user's info.

If you needs to add custom fields without using a plugin: [**Check this Tutorial**](http://tipsforwordpress.com/wordpress/add-custom-field-to-register-form/). This will teach you step by step How to Add Custom Field to Register Form.

Cheers !!!

Comment: FYI- Tutorial Link is now dead.